# Flask - как получить последнюю запись из БД?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Есть следующие таблицы в БД:

```
class Car_Log(db.Model):
    rent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    car_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('car.car_id'))
    time_begin = db.Column(db.DateTime, default = datetime.now)
    time_end = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    time_sum = db.Column(db.Float())
    cost = db.Column(db.Float)

class Car(db.Model):
    car_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    availability = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True)
```

В одной из предыдущих сессий в таблицу добавляется запись в Car_Log с rent_id (поле уникальное). Т.е. сначала создается запись и добавляется time_begin, привязанное к car_id.

Как в текущей сессии найти последнюю запись с car_id (у которой, естественно, не записано еще time_end) вызвать ее и добавить time_end.

Вопрос только в том как найти запись по car_id

Мой вариант, указанный ниже, не работает:

```
if request.form.get('rent') == 'rent':
    new_car_log = Car_Log()
    db.session.add(new_car_log)
    car.availability = 0
    new_car_log.car_id = car.car_id
    new_car_log.time_begin = datetime.now()

if request.form.get('free') == 'free':
    new_car_log = session.query(Car_Log).order_by(Car_Log.car_id.desc()).first()
    car.availability = 1
    new_car_log.time_end = datetime.now()
```

Comment: Что конкретно подразумевается под не работает? Исключение? new_car_log оказывается пустым? new_car_log не пустой, но запись не меняется?

Comment: Если вопрос к session.query(Car_Log).order_by(Car_Log.car_id.desc()).first() то ругается на session. А как его импортировать не знаю. Перебрал все варианты предлагаемые pycharme

Comment: Ну так что пишет? Он не ругается, а сообщает что не так. Вот что он пишет надо прочитать и понять суть.

Comment: NameError: name 'session' is not defined

Comment: А зачем обращаться к session? Откуда-то скопировано? 
Судя по коду выше стоит попробовать session заменить на db.session.

Comment: Спасибо! нашел данный код где-то здесь же)) исправил, ошибка пропала, но
            new_car_log.time_end = datetime.now() не выполняется (time_end - NULL после выполнения). При этом, time_begin появляется, кнопки меняют свои состояния

Comment: Возможно коммит не сделан. Вообще тяжело что-то делать если непонятен сам механизм работы sql alchemy. Сначала не помешало бы парочку туториалов изучить, как с sql alchemy работать.

Comment: @Alpensin спасибо! Вроде помогли Ваши советы